# Shimano 8000 Battery Reverse Engineering

Tags: shimano, battery

I am on a mission to reverse-engineer the Shimano 8000 battery, with the purpose being to allow Shimano 8000 batteries to be used with a non-Shimano controller.

The reason is to have two motors on my Bullitt cargo bike - a Shimano 8000 mid-motor, and a  Grin-sourced Bafang G311 hub motor.

I have two of the 8000 batteries, but I'm reluctant to open them up.

I have several friends who are expert (and now retired) EE motor control designers.  I'm hoping they can look at the BMS PCB and get an idea of what Shimano has done in general.

I have access to a full set of EE tools - oscilloscopes, logic analyzers, etc. - everything you need to design, build and test PCBs specifically for industrial servo control and amplifiers/controllers.

I don't want to replicate what Shimano has done, just understand enough to spoof the batteries into working with a third-party controller.

Can anyone help?

I need as much info as possible on the internals of the 8000 battery.

1) Anyone want to loan or sell me a bricked Shimano battery?

2) Can anyone post or send a good photo of the BMS PCB?

Let's do this.  It can't be that hard.

Comment: Not an answer but I'm wondering: why are you reluctant to open up one of the batteries? You should probably have enough space to fit a second bms (for discharge through a second discharge connector for the non shimano motor) without many  alterations to the housing. You could keep using the original bms for charging. Original bms will have active battery balancing most likely. Which should still be active even when discharging through second bms, ensuring a properly balanced pack. You could even bypass the bms completely for discharge (connect plus and minus directly to outgoing  connector).

Comment: Depending on the model/features you want you can get a 10s bms anywhere from 4usd to 14usd. Regarding bypassing bms completely for discharge: you should definitely consider placing a fuse in one of the outgoing wires when doing this. In case you short the battery connector the fuse will blow and damage to the battery will be prevented. Also when bypassing the bms completely you lose the 'low voltage cutoff ' function that most bms's have (which prevents cell over discharge). However the controller should in general shut off when voltage is low. Mine shuts off at +/-3v per cell ,2.8v under load

Comment: You should check your controller's cutoff voltage though to be sure.

Comment: This might be more on topic at Electronics.stackexchange.com because its about batteries and charging, and the bike component is tangential.

Comment: Hey, thanks guys for the comments.  A second BMS - a very interesting idea.  Will research and will post any other progress.

Comment: Other than physical space, I guess there's no reason not to have two BMS on a given bank of batteries, and use a switch to toggle between them....or why not use both simultaneously?  Use two BMS's on each of two batteries, send the outputs of each to the different controllers.  Hmmm....have to think about this, with respect to the guess as to how Shimano is proprietorizing their BMS.

Comment: Hey again, Maarten in the Netherlands!

Comment: Hey again, Maarten in the Netherlands!   Your post DID give me a great idea - I'm going to take the batteries to a battery repair shop about 2 hours from my house here in California.  They will install a second, non-proprietary, BMS board on one Shimano battery, "underneath" the Shimano BMS board, and replace the Shimano BMS board with a generic BMS board on the second battery.  I'll parallel the two generic BMS boards together, so a single charger will then have access to the cells of both batteries, bypassing the Shimano BMS on charge.  THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR IDEA!!  You made my week!!

Comment: I'd be very interested to know if any of you had luck installing a second parallel BMS to Shimano Steps battery without killing the Shimano BMS. I managed to trigger some protection function of a Shimano  BT-E6010 battery just by doing a bit of direct discharging and it now it is a brick with a lot of good cells. In another question here the same happened by attempting to direct charge it.